# Создание таблицы на Laravel с динамически изменяемым количеством колонок

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Создаю сайт на Laravel и столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно создать таблицу, отображение БД, в которую в реальном времени добавляют колонки. Поля этих колонок своего рода индикаторы, если значение поля 1 - то отрисовывается в поле рисунок галочки, если 0 - то отрисовывается красный крест(с занесением изменившегося значения в БД).[image: Так выглядит набросок таблицы]
Вот так я это реализовал без JS, просто используя возможности Laravel.

Но нашел вот этот Yajra\Datatables фреймворк.

Решил реализовать на нем, так как в моем варианте не было не постраничного разделения, ни поиска, ни фильтра, но столкнулся с тем, что не знаю как выводить динамически значения этих добавленных столбцов,да еще заменяя их на картинку-кнопку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контроллер:

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Lot;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;

class DatatablesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays datatables front end view
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('test-table', ['lotsTable' => Lot::all()] );
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function anyData()
    {
        $users = Lot::select(['article', 'lotdesc', 'proportion', 'lotsource', 'price', 'supplynum', 'comment', 'vk'])->get();
        return Datatables::of($users)->make();
    }

}
```

Роуты:

```
 Route::get('datatables',['uses'=>'DatatablesController@getIndex', 'as' => 'datatables']);
    Route::get('datatables/{data}',['uses'=>'DatatablesController@anyData', 'as' => 'datatables.data']);
```

Вьюха:

```
@extends('test')

@section('content')
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Артикль</th>
            <th>Описание лота</th>
            <th>Замеры</th>
            <th>Источник лота</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <th>Номер обновы</th>
            <th>Комментарий</th>

            <?php
            $columnNum = 0;
            foreach ($lotsTable as $row) {
                foreach ($row['attributes'] as $key => $val) {
                    if ($columnNum < 12) {
                        $columnNum++;
                        continue;
                    } else
                        echo "<th>$key</th>";
                }
                break;
            }
            ?>

            <th><a href="javascript:;" onclick="openModal({title: 'Добавить площадку', type: 'addColumn'})"
                   class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> + </a></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
@stop

@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! url('datatables/data') !!}',
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

Да и вообще, обьясните что лучше для моей задачи использовать, какие технологии, может в Larovel есть уже то что мне нужно, но я просто не нашел это.

Answer (score 1):

Я тут как то думал делать [компонент](https://github.com/orangeShadow/vue-data-grid) типа дата-грида, там есть пример, если не понятно спрашивай

смотри есть составной компонент data-grid, состоит из data-row

[data-raw](https://github.com/orangeShadow/vue-data-grid/blob/master/src/components/data-row.vue) выглядит так страшно, потому что он собирается руками, что бы была возможность передать туда html (как раз например картинки или кнопки), иначе никак. Используем описанную в документации к Vue  функцию render (которая помогает нам динамически отрендерить компонент с передачей туда любых параметров, в том числе callback)

Пример передачи html или повесить действие на создаваемую сущность при использовании render

---

```
export default {
    render(c){
        var self = this;
        var data = this.data;

        return c('a',{
            attrs:{
                href:data.link
            },
            domProps: {
                innerHTML: data.html
            },          
            on:{
                click: function(){
                        item.callback(self.data,self.index,self.$parent.data);
                    }
            },                      
            'class':item.class,
        })

    }
}
```

[data-grid](https://github.com/orangeShadow/vue-data-grid/blob/master/src/components/data-grid.vue) - это по факту отображение таблицы и передача параметров в data-raw

собственно файле [App.vue](https://github.com/orangeShadow/vue-data-grid/blob/master/src/App.vue) идет подстановка данных в компонент дата grid, сейчас все там статически, но благодаря тому что мы передаем туда callback мы можем повесить обработку любых маршрутов в том числе получение данных с сервера

если есть вопросы задавайте

Answer (score 0):

Вы выбрали хороший способ брать данные через отдельный путь.

Для отрисовки таблицы можно использовать React или vue.js

Вот видео туториалы которые вам могут помочь

https://laracasts.com/series/do-you-react

https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step